# Expressing A = LU in smaller matrix size

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering if we can express A as the product of a 5 x 2 matrix and a 2 x 5 matrix for A = LU where:

A =
\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1&0&-1\\6&6&1&1&-2\\-3&-6&1&-2&1\\6&6&1&1&-2\\0&2&-1&1&0\end{bmatrix}

L =
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\2&1&0&0&0\\-1&-2&1&0&0\\2&1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

U =
\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1&0&-1\\0&2&-1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

Which factorization can I use and how do I solve it to express A as the product of a 5 x 2 matrix and a 2 x 5 matrix?

Comment: Hi OP! Welcome to Math SE! For a better presentation of your question, please typeset the matrices properly!

Comment: @EthanMark Thanks for letting me know that I have to typeset the matrices properly!

Comment: @EthanMark Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but not really. It's been too long since I've used linear algebra and my knowledge of it a little rusty now, so I wouldn't want to be misleading you in any way! I'm sure there are much more learned people out there who can help you! Perhaps you are getting low views at the moment because you posted this over the weekend, when I believe there are lesser users on the site.